# Module not found: modprobe

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have written a simple hello world kernel module, compiled it and install in `/lib/modules/kernel_version/extra/` path.

With `insmod` its getting loaded properly, but with `modprobe` i am getting an error

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module hello_world.ko not found.
```

I have installed all the per-requisite.

Here is Makefile to compile and install:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD)  modules
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build  M=$(PWD)  modules_install
```

Please tell me how to get is done.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 10):

This is because `modprobe` inserts modules by reading a file called **modules.dep** under **/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/**. So after compiling and installing your module make sure you recreate this dependency file once again.

Here is how it is done

> 1. After installation of your module, check whether it is copied to /lib/modules/
> 2. if it is found, then go to -> **/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/** and use **depmod** command to create the dependency list of your new module.

> Once this is done, you will be able to locate your module name under the file **/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/modules.dep**.

After this you can use `modprobe` to insert your module.

EDIT:

Below is the `Makefile` I used to build with root permission and test.

```
target ?= hello_world
obj-m = $(target).o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules_install

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Same error:
once i run Makefile module is already located in /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/modules.dep .

Comment: INSTALL /home/vishal/test/linux_dd/hello_world.ko
Can't read private key
  DEPMOD  3.13.0-24-generic
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'

Comment: above is some output snippet from makefile.

Comment: Did you use `root` permission when using `modules_install` and `depmod` ? If not then use `sudo` and try again

Comment: sorry , i did not get you.
please explain.

Comment: With the above mentioned `Makefile` I compiled and installed a module `hello_world`. then used `depmod` command in the /lib/modules/(uname -r) directory to create/recreate `modules.dep` file. After which I tried `modprobe` command to insert my module

Comment: try using strace with the modprobe command. you should be able to see what path names it's trying to access when searching for the file.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem once. My problem was that I didn't remove the extension when giving the command. I.e.

```
modprobe foo.ko
```

gives the above error. But this:

```
modprobe foo
```

works!